# Can I use class names instead of id when I setting parameters in eclipse cucumber?

Tags: java, eclipse, cucumber

I have this code but it does not pass the scenario.

Can I use `findElement(By.className(link))` instead of `findElement(By.id(link)).click()`?

What is the wrong with my passing?

```
@When("^I click on the \"([^\"]*)\" link.$")
public void I_click_on_the_link(String link) throws Throwable {
    driver.findElement(By.className(link)).click();
```

Comment: What is wrong in trying it out?

Comment: I don't like "when I click on ___ link" steps because it's not behavior. Behavior is what the user wants to do. They click on links because that's how they get somewhere they want to go. What they want is to go somewhere. 'When I go to "my account settings"' might be better.

Comment: It says that  Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":""}
      Command duration or timeout: 1.61 seconds

Comment: Thank you for your comment< i will correct them in my next step. Still I am new to cucumber and I learn about it these days. So, I valued your comments.